# Rendering using OpenSG python bindings

Tags: c++, python, rendering

Hey!! I'm looking for python bindings for opensg 1.8.. I haven't been able to find it. I have read somethin about pyopengs. Is it still available? I am working on linux platform (ubuntu). If anyone could direct me to it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The homepage and source code is on google code:  [pyOpenSG Project](http://code.google.com/p/pyopensg/)

As one of the creators of pyOpenSG, I can tell you that it is definitely still alive and kicking.  We use it in production software all the time.  It has become so stable for us though that we don't often update the code base.  The python binding generator that we use ([py++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygccxml/)) just keeps everything working between revisions.